# javascript constructor this isn't bound correctly

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, member-functions

Problem: I define a constructor in JavaScript, I've tried almost every pattern I can think of / Google. For some reason no matter what I do when I call a member function of that object the `this` keyword is always bound to `window`. I don't know what to do.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/za6SN/2/

Comment: The semantics of the `this` keyword in javascript are relatively straightforward, but not very obvious.  This might help: [stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the method reference as `ball.draw`, its `this` is set to `window` because it has lost its context.

The best way is to [use an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132169/javascript-constructor-this-isnt-bound-correctly/6132183#6132183). The other way is not recommended (it invokes an `eval()`) so I won't even mention it here.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
setInterval(function() {ball.draw()}, 50);
```

Without you will only pass the reference to the function ball.draw and this will point to window